# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Unlock generated files with buildtime.sh script

Tags: iphone, bash, shell, ibm-mobilefirst, lockfile

I am using IBM Worklight 6.1 and trying to copy a file into `iphone/native/www/worklight` folder
The file I am trying to copy/erase is cordova_plugins.js, For that purpose I edited the `buildtime.sh` shell script by adding the line:

```
cp "${SRCROOT}/cordova_plugins.js" "${SRCROOT}/www/default/worklight/cordova_plugins.js"
```

This does not work after deploying for iPhone, and returns a `permission denied` error.
After unlocking the file `cordova_plugins.js` (manually), the script works without errors.

So, I tried to unlock the file with the same script shell, by adding

```
chflags nouchg "${SRCROOT}/www/default/worklight/cordova_plugins.js"
```

just before the `cp` instruction, but It does not seems to change anything (no additional error, but the issue remains the same.)

Is there a way to unlock the `/www/worklight` files in project settings or programatically? How to do that with my buildtime.sh script ? Any other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

In Worklight, this file was not meant to be played around with (per our discussion in another question of yours).

To work around it, try this:
Go to Xcode preferences and unlock all files by selecting the "Automatically unlock files" option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I am looking for : in this way it will be only working on my mac, and if someone else get the code from source control, he must change this too, or get the error

Comment: Understood, but you asked for a workaround and this is a valid workaround your co-workers can do as well, until you find a way to make it work using a script. ;)

Comment: Also, if you ever re-generate your Worklight project, this file may be overwritten, so your script change will be lost. So it is better to do this outside of the Worklight project, and via Xcode sounds much better in this case.

Comment: By the way, 
I think that buildtime.sh script is executed after copying resources to the binary file, since my wokaround works only the second time I run the projet for now. Is there a way to execute pre-build script ?

Comment: Maybe there is some Xcode option to add scripts and call them at specific times. I don't know, try googling for that.

Comment: @WiPhone, if my answer helped resolve your problem, please mark as answered.